# Scraping a dynamic html page with hidden html

Tags: r, xml, rvest, stringr, rcurl

I wanted to extract some log data from a dynamic webpage with multiple tabs, when I do screen scrape it works, but when I pass the url through the url the html does not provide the details in some tabs (for example, in this case, details under activity, in all tabs.

```
  library(RCurl)
  library(stringr)
  library(XML)
  library(RCurl)
  library(stringr)
  library(XML)
 library(rvest)  
 url<- c("https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQCPP-645")
 html<- getURL((url, followlocation = TRUE)
 doc = htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
 evs <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class='issue-data-block']", xmlValue)
```

I would like to extract the events from the webpage but the html does not automatically show the information in the tabs (which is under the all tabs under the lower pane)

I am expecting the output as follows:

```
  rows  evs 
   1      S A created issue - 25/Apr/19 15:48 Highlight in document.    
   2      Justin Bertram made changes - 25/Apr/19 17:53 Field Original Value 
          New 
         Value  Comment [ I'm using Firefox, and it's working no problem. It's 
         just HTML so    there shouldn't be any browser compatibility issues. 
         My guess is that Firefox  is holding on to an older, cached version or 
         something. Try opening a "private browsing" window and trying it from 
         there. ] Highlight in document.

   3      Timothy Bish made changes - 25/Apr/19 18:10 Resolution Fixed [ 1 ] 
            Status 
          Open [ 1 ] Closed [ 6 ] Highlight in document.
   4       Timothy Bish made transition - 25/Apr/19 18:10 Open Closed 2h 22m 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to scrape html but rather use REST api. The reason is that the part of content of a page is built using javascript so it is not enough to just scrape html but eveluate JS as well. For example in your case you can invoke REST api of Jira to query the data you need. Technically this is not really different from what you're already doing.

For example to fetch comments you invoke `https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/issue/AMQCPP-645/comment` which returns list of comment objects. Each one has it is own URL (e.g. `https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/issue/13230124/comment/16826237`). The same can be repeated for other tabs.

Comment: I am interested in all activities tab, not just comments, is this achievable?

Comment: Yes. After you parsed data for comments you can call REST method (another one) that would return work log, transitions, etc. You should only consider that you have to be authorized in order to query some kind of data (whatever way you're using).

Comment: ok thanks, how do I request the jira api authentication? is there a link? let me try..